# Use of MessageBoxW in Visual C++ to output multiple strings which are added together

Tags: c++, string, visual-studio-2008, visual-c++, messagebox

How would I output a mix of different variables in a LPCWSTR to show it up in a MessageBoxW?
I am using Visual C++ 2008 Express and I am a very beginner. My problem is to add different variables to a string. It basically says always: **cannot add two pointers**. Why I cannot add two strings or a string and an integer together with the regular "+" sign like in all other programming languages?
I used Google and found stringstream, but this did not worked out for me, so please don't suggest it anymore to me.

I have this three types of variables:
(Yes, my program runs with unicode and it has to be that way! I have defined unicode in the header.)

```
wchar_t username[255];
wchar_t windir1[MAX_PATH];
wchar_t computername1[255];
```

Then I have a variable for my MessageBox:

```
LPCWSTR message1;
```

And I have the code for my MessageBox:

```
MessageBox(NULL, message1, L"Info", MB_OK);
```

How would I add now all three variables together to output.
My following code doesn't work:

```
message1 = "Computername: " + computername1 + "\n" + "Username: " + username1 + "\n" + "Windows Directory: " + windir1;
```

The error is something like "cannot convert..." and "cannot add two pointers..." I tried already everything or the plus sign ('+') is illegal.
Is there any text macro to add strings easily together or something similar?
I found nothing satisfying on my research. Most examples where for Borland like .c_str() which
isn't available with Visual Studio C++.

One variable works for output as long is not anything added to it:

```
LPCWSTR message1 = _T(computername1);
```

But how I said I would like to put out "message1" with the plus operator and multiple strings added together.

This construct already doesn't work it says: **Cannot add two pointers!**

```
LPCWSTR message1 = _T(computername1) + _T("My Test String");
```

What pointers?

Comment: Hopefully you are aware that `LPCWSTR` is "long pointer to character (wide) string". You should probably look into [StringCchCat](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ff468908(v=vs.85).aspx) and [wstrcat](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f0151s4x.aspx), a lot of string manip functions are provided.

Comment: Neither of those links are for 2012 only. In fact, the first specifically links to the 2008 version of the documentation. Your browser preferences may be set to 2012, though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Addition will not work.

You must allocate memory and copy your string elsewhere. A good way is wsprintf, or a C++ class std::wstring which does support addition. However, it is better to avoid widechars (UTF-16) and do the addition with a regular std::string. Pass them to MessageBoxW() with boost::nowide. For more details, please see utf8everywhere.org.

Comment: wstring message2 = wstring(computername1) + "123"